# Covert commas to whitespace

Tags: javascript, string

How to convert - `alice,bob,charlie` to `alice bob charlie`? 
Is there some kind of .join or .strip operation for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
var s = "alice,bob,charlie";
s.split(",").join(" ");
```